# How to make small changes in project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have some Rails project (**project1**) that is published in Github.
I would like to build another one Rails project (**project2**) based on **project1**.
**Project2** is dealing with database that has the same structure as the project1 database. But **project1** database has other content.
**Project1** has several static pages that will be changed in **Project2**.
Moreover, there will be small changes in **Project2** site title and site menu text.
Logic, algorithm and so on are the same in Project1 and Project2.

I would like to get rid redundancy. I don't want to create a new repository in Github for **Project2**. I want to build **Project2** on **Project1** code but with other database.yml and some changes in static pages and site title text.

What is the appropriate (the best) way to do this?

**UPDATE**
Also I would like changes in logic (controller, models so on) of **project1** will be reflected to **project2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can branch off of your main project by doing something like `git branch project2` and then `git checkout project2`, and all the work that you do from that point forward will only occur in `project2`.

If you need to return to `project1`, you can just commit or stash your changes and do `git checkout project1` to return to the previous code.

Additionally, if you need to take some of the changes from `project1` and "bring them in" to your `project2` branch, you can use `git cherry-pick [SHA]`. To figure out the SHA hash, you'll need to check log for that branch, i.e. `git log project1` and take the part at the top that says something like `commit 5479d1834c281b29a7948e426e73bfdf27032569`, where the long string of numbers and letters is the SHA hash.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get rid redundancy.

You are able to avoid redundancem just by creating the new **Project2** as an additional project in [github](/questions/tagged/github), but in order to reuse the code of **Project1** in it. You shall form the **Project1** as a gem, publish it. and inside in the **Project2** initializers just include the **Project1**s' ones, and the same thing you shall do for `views`, `controllers`, and `models`. So essentially in the **Project2** you need to create only parts that should changed specifically for the project.

So just use the two things:

1. Recursive importing of Rails features you are able to accomplish with [Rails Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). So

   > Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide functionality to their host applications.
   >   Therefore, engines and applications can be thought of almost the same thing, just with subtle difference.
2. You then be able to add, and use the `#require_project1` method, which will load a submodule from the **Project1** to reuse it, or to change it in the **Project2**.